# while using iframe its width and height doesn't refreshes on runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am using iframe for targeting my URL . Issue is when i open a page whose content is large it stores its height and width and doesn't changes when i open a page whose page content is small. Is there any other way for targeting my URL other than iframe. Here is my Java script :

```
    function autoResize(id){
     var newheight;
     var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
    newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
    newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
}

document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
```

and here is my html Code :

```
    <div class="row">
    <iframe width="100%" seamless="seamless" height="100px" scrolling="no" style="margin-right:300px background: #FFFFFF;border:none" id="iframe1" name="NewFrame1" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('iframe1');"></iframe>
    </div><!-- /.row (main row) -->
```

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The size of the content of an iframe is usually set according to the size of the window, i.e. iframe element on the main page. The content of the iframe needs to have a fixed size, then your code might work.

Comment: You should append targeted page content inside main page DOM without using any iframe. For example, you could use [$.fn.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: guys can you please tell me programatically? Thank u :)